# How to test post login pages for sql injection using sqlmap

Tags: sqlmap

I have an application in which post login a page is vulnerable to SQL injection. Post login from the browser I captured the request via burp of that vulnerable page and fed the data to sqlmap. But I'm getting the following error.

`[15:45:24] [INFO] testing connection to the target URL
sqlmap got a 302 redirect to 'http://localhost:80/dvwa/login.php'. Do you want to follow? [Y/n]  Y`

`[8]+  Stopped sqlmap -u http://localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli/?id=2`

This is the data I entered

`sqlmap -u http://localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli/?id=2&Submit=Submit --cookie="security=low; PHPSESSID=loif1hgpc539lith3rvbe1coh1" --dbs`

Kindly advise hot to fix this.

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would need to submit the query with the parameter `id`

This might help you:
`sqlmap -u http://localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli/?id=2&Submit=Submit --cookie="security=low; PHPSESSID=loif1hgpc539lith3rvbe1coh1" -p id --dbs`